# PackProtocolException: invalid advertisement when using the jgitflow-maven-plugin withing a jenkins job

Tags: java, git, maven, git-flow, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I am using the following jgitflow-maven-plugin(created and no longer maintained) by the Atlassian team. Whenever I try to execute a release-start from within a Jenkins job I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.PackProtocolException: invalid advertisement of <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

The plugin is imported like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>external.atlassian.jgitflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>jgitflow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-m5.1</version>
</plugin>
```

It is configured in the pom.xml as follows:

1. SCM config

```xml
<scm>
    <url>https://myOwnRepo.com/test</url>
    <connection>scm:git:https://myOwnRepo.com/test.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://myOwnRepo.com/test.git</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

2. Plugin configuration

```xml
<configuration>
    <flowInitContext>
        <masterBranchName>master</masterBranchName>
        <developBranchName>dev</developBranchName>
        <versionTagPrefix>v</versionTagPrefix>
    </flowInitContext>

    <pushFeatures>true</pushFeatures>
    <pushHotfixes>true</pushHotfixes>

    <username>myRepoUser</username>
    <password>myRepoPassword</password>

    <allowUntracked>true</allowUntracked>
</configuration>
```

3. Other configurations

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>release</id>

        <goals>
            <goal>release-start</goal>
            <goal>release-finish</goal>
        </goals>

        <configuration>
            <scmCommentPrefix>[RELEASE]</scmCommentPrefix>
        </configuration>
    </execution>

    <execution>
        <id>feature</id>

        <goals>
            <goal>feature-start</goal>
            <goal>feature-finish</goal>
        </goals>

        <configuration>
            <allowSnapshots>true</allowSnapshots>
            <scmCommentPrefix>[FEATURE]</scmCommentPrefix>
        </configuration>

    </execution>

    <execution>
        <id>hotfix</id>

        <goals>
            <goal>hotfix-start</goal>
            <goal>hotfix-finish</goal>
        </goals>

        <configuration>
            <scmCommentPrefix>[HOTFIX]</scmCommentPrefix>
        </configuration>

    </execution>
</executions>
```

I have also tried changing the version of the following dependencies:

```
<groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
<artifactId>jsch</artifactId>

<groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
<artifactId>jsch.agentproxy.sshagent</artifactId>

<groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
<artifactId>jsch.agentproxy.jsch</artifactId>

<groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
<artifactId>jsch.agentproxy.usocket-jna</artifactId>
```

The project is behind a proxy that is set using line arguments. It is cloned using https as per the scm configs. Also, in order to connect, it uses a token and not the password.

On my local machine, everything seems to be working and the only difference against the Jenkins job seems to be the proxy which is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the problem that was causing the wrong behavior of the jenkins job was the proxy(as expected).

The Jenkins instance was running behind a proxy. Whenever the maven-jgitflow-plugin was trying to reach the git repo, it would get a 403 page as a response from the repo.

After changing the proxy configs the error disappeared and the plugin worked.